# What is "-noall_load" flag replacement on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, ld

I used "all_load" and "noall_load" ld flags in my project, but the compiler/ld reported that noall_load was being ignored. What's the replacement of it?

```
$ cc ... -Wl,-all_load lib1 -Wl,-noall_load lib2 lib3 ...
...
ld: warning: option -noall_load is obsolete and being ignored
...
$ ld -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-253.3
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em
LTO support using: Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)
```

Comment: Could you explain your use case more? What are you trying to achieve by using these linker options?

Comment: @SimonKissane I edited my post. In a word, lib1 should be linked as a whole archive, while lib2 and lib3 shouldn't. The reason why lib1 should be linked like this is out of scope.

Comment: Instead of -all_load, you can use -force_load to target specific archives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to `man ld`:

```
     -noall_load
             This is the default.  This option is obsolete.
```

In other words, `-noall_load` is useless, because it disables loading all members of static archive libraries, but that is disabled by default anyway. The linker warning just serves to let you know that you are passing a useless option to the linker. While a useless option isn't as such doing any harm to your build, useless options have the potential to confuse and distract people, and might cause the build to fail with an error if the option is removed completely in some future version.

**Update**: Per your comment, you are trying to do `-all_load` on some archives but not others. You cannot do that by combining `-all_load` and `-noall_load` in the same linker invocation, but you can do it using `-force_load`.